# pyCurl spikes CPU when I add option MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE

Tags: python, curl, libcurl, pycurl

My app uses PyCurl to upload multiple files one by one. It works all good with all cURL options and CPU consumption remains below 1%. When I add MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE option to throttle bandwidth, CPU consumption goes to 100%.

```
c.setopt(c.MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE, int(rate_limit))
```

Further investigation reveals, it only happens on OS X 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Are you working with libcurl < 7.31.0?
- Also: are you using the progress function?

If yes, I would say you may have hit a bug that has been fixed in [libcurl 7.31.0](http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_31_0), i.e [curl_easy_perform: avoid busy-looping](http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1238/):

> I am using pycurl in a small script to download coursera videos [...] it hangs 1 core of the machine  all the time [...] I can confirm that this occurs, and only when **rate limiting for upload/download is in place**.

*The patch can be seen [here](https://github.com/bagder/curl/commit/0feeab7).*

Comment: It is indeed libcurl 7.30.0 issue. Thanks for pointing me to exact solution.